# Getting the data of near wifi networks ( error in the code)

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I'm trying to have an application that gets the specifications of near wifi networks to combine it with another application but I have an error in the AndroidManifest.xml file that I do not know how to fix. The error is in the line android:label="@string/title_activity_list_wifi" shown below. Regards

```
// AndroidManifest.xml file.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wifi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
    android:name="com.example.wifi.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.example.wifi.ListWifiActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_list_wifi">
    </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
// src/com.example.wifi/MainActivity.java
package com.example.wifi;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WifiManager mainWifiObj;
WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
ListView list;
String wifis[];
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
mainWifiObj.startScan();
}
protected void onPause() {
unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
super.onResume();
}
class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
}
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you think it might be useful to tell us what the error is?

Comment: It says no resource found to match the given name of the line android:label="@string/title_activity_list_wifi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:label="@string/title_activity_list_wifi"` Is referring to the string `title_activity_list_wifi` in your strings.xml file (more about string resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), which apparently doesn't exist.

There are 2 things you can do to solve this:
-Use a hardcoded string instead of a reference:

```
 android:label="This activity has a list of wifi networks"
```

-Add the string to the strings.xml file (res/values):

```
 <string name="title_activity_list_wifi">This activity has a list of wifi networks</string>
```

Comment: Your welcome! Please press the green mark below the up amd downvote buttons, thank you.